# how to count user specific comments on a hasMany relationship using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm

how can I count comments of a specific user in this scenario, A user hasMany books, A book hasMany chapters, chapters belongsTo a book and Chapter hasMany comments and comments belongsTo a chapter?

So far this is what I have done but I am not certain if this is correct as I have done through the example from the laravel documentation.

```
    public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
               'App\comments', 'App\Chapter','id','chapter_id'
    );
}
```

and this is my loop

```
@foreach($user_comments as $comment) {{$comment->comments->count()}} @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two relationships. Add this to your `User` model:

```
public function chapters()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Chapter::class, Book::class);
}
```

And this to `Chapter`:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Then you can count the comments like this:

```
$user->load('chapters.comments');
$count = $user->chapters->pluck('comments')->collapse()->count();
```

Comment: where do I put this code?

in the view or controller?

$user->load('chapters.comments');
$count = $user->chapters->pluck('comments')->collapse()->count();

Comment: In your controller or as an accessor  in your `User` model (e.g. `getCommentsCountAttribute()`). Then you can use `{{ $user->commentsCount }}` in your view.

Comment: unfortunately I am receiving an error 

Call to a member function load() on null

`@foreach($user_comments as $user) 
{{ $user->commentsCount }} 
@endforeach`

Comment: In `getCommentsCountAttribute()` you have to replace `$user` with `$this`.

Comment: No luck brah! I have been trying but nothing, I have been getting this error, Trying to get property 'commentsCount' of non-object

this is what is my User model

   public function getCommentsCountAttribute(){
    $this->load('chapters.comments');
    $count = $this->chapters->pluck('comments')->collapse()->count();
    }


this is what I am passing to the view 

->with('author_comments',Auth::user());

and this is my foreach loop in the view

@foreach($author_comments as $author) {{ $author->commentsCount }} @endforeach

Comment: In `getCommentsCountAttribute()` you have to replace `$count` with `return`. Since `author_comments` is only one user, you can't use a loop in your view. Just use `{{ $author_comments->commentsCount }}`.

Comment: MUCH APPRECIATION FROM ME TO YOU MAN!